# how can I sum nested if statements in Excel without VBA?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

How can I do the following without unnecessary repetition using just excel formulas?

=IF(A1="Holiday",8,IF(A1="Sick Leave",7, IF(A1="Bank Holiday",5,0)))   +    IF(A2="Holiday",8,IF(A2="Sick Leave",7, IF(A2="Bank Holiday",5,0)))    +    IF(A3="Holiday",8,IF(A3="Sick Leave",7, IF(A3="Bank Holiday",5,0))) + ..... for the next 50 rows from A1 to A50

Thank you very much

Comment: You could use the [switch](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/switch-function-47ab33c0-28ce-4530-8a45-d532ec4aa25e) function, but only on Excel 2016 and newer. (or 2019 ??)

Comment: @Luuk 2019 and 365.

Comment: now i only need to find the page where i said 2016 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an extra column in which you write the formula

=IF(A1="Holiday",8,IF(A1="Sick Leave",7, IF(A1="Bank Holiday",5,0)))

And then sum this column for the result.

If you do not want to use the extra column you can write a formula as follows:
=countifs(a1:a51;"Holiday")*8+countifs(a1:a51;"Sick Leave")*7+countifs(a1:a51;"Bank Holiday")*5
This formula counts the instances of Holiday/Sick Leave/Bank Holiay in the column and then it multiplays this by the value you want.

Comment: The second approach seems interesting and a smart one. I will test it now and come back toy you

Answer (score 0):

```
=
    MATCH(A1,{"","","","","Bank Holiday","","Sick Leave","Holiday"},0)
  + MATCH(A2,{"","","","","Bank Holiday","","Sick Leave","Holiday"},0)
  + MATCH(A3,{"","","","","Bank Holiday","","Sick Leave","Holiday"},0)
  + ...
```

Or, as an [array formula](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/guidelines-and-examples-of-array-formulas-7d94a64e-3ff3-4686-9372-ecfd5caa57c7),

```
{=SUM(MATCH(A1:A50,{"","","","","Bank Holiday","","Sick Leave","Holiday"},0))}
```

But better just have a lookup table on a sheet somewhere with these values so that you don't have to repeat them each time.

Comment: Is this actually shorter/betterReadable then the repeated IF ?

Comment: @Luuk Yes, because there is no nesting.

Comment: Thank you very much. But the above answer would mean I have to write this 50 times. Would you please elaborate more on the other solution that requires a Vlookup table? Thank you GSerg

Comment: @Saber It would only replace the `{"","","","","Bank Holiday","","Sick Leave","Holiday"}` with the address of that table, e.g. `B1:B8`, the result would remain the same. With an array formula you won't even need that, although you still can do it too.